# Electron & NodeJS Project Management

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In a server environment, I expect to write URL paths to query for data. In `Electron`, because I can use `NodeJS` in any part of the application with normal `JavaScript`, there seems to be no 'separation' between the two.

Where should most of the code be, especially if when using `NodeJS`? In the `main.js` file, or in the application's `JavaScript` file? Additionally, if a result from the `NodeJS` code is being written to the `HTML dom`, should it be written directly from the same code or stored and then written in normal `JavaScript`?

What is normal or good practice in `Electron`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new with electron and don't know where to start, I recommend to you to download this example and take a look to the reedme.txt and the code inside, it will lead you to the path to begin your app.

[Take a look](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps)

Comment: These examples seem to show what I thought, that NodeJS/JS/Dom interactions are close together. I'll try to keep it modular though!

Comment: @user1679669 fantastic! Don't forget voting and accepting if you found the answer useful ;)